# Shorten mapping and concat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I get an array with `person` objects. A `person` can have several `houses`:

```
 person.houses => ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy
```

Some houses can belong to several `persons`. In my code I would like to get all unique `houses` for the persons that are in the Array.

This is a long version of the code:

```
 def persons_houses(persons)
   unique_houses = []

   persons.each do |person|
     person.houses.each do |house|
        unique_houses << house if !unique_houses.include? house
     end
   end

   unique_houses
 end
```

**Do you know a shorter code for this `persons_houses(persons)` method?**

I was thinking of mapping the persons houses, concat them at the same time and then return unique values

Something like: (But this is not valid Ruby)

```
persons.map { |person| concat(person.houses) }.uniq
```

**Thanks for your help!**

Comment: This feels like it should happen in the database query, not in a Ruby array. Do I understand correctly that you have a many-to-many relationship between House and Person? If so, is it implemented as a has_and_belongs_to_many, or has_many: through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each person has many houses, and a single house may belong to many people? How about:

```
persons.map(&:houses).flatten.uniq
```

Comment: This will work, but it creates an unnecessary array that could be very large, depending on the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a single database query and without making an Array to parse through. Assuming you have a relation table (not sure how else a Person can have many Houses and a House can have many Persons), and assuming your relation table is called `ownerships`, you would do:

```
House.joins(:ownerships).where(ownerships: {person_id: persons.ids}).uniq
```

This is much faster and much more memory-efficient than the other answer suggested, and it also leaves you with an ActiveRecord_Relation so you can further scope the result.